# Is there a way to force Google Photos to recognize new faces?

Tags: google-photos

I have "Face grouping" enabled in my Google account and I can see around 10 faces successfully tagged when I go to my Albums. However, there's a lot of other people who are not tagged, as well as some unrecognized photos of people who are already tagged.

Is there a way to force Google Photos to run the facial recognition algorithm on a given photo, so that it adds new faces or maps a new photo to an existing face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: this feature has now been added to Google Photos! You can select any face and either create a new person or map it to someone in your library.**  Old answer below:

---

After waiting for a couple of weeks, the last ~two years worth of photos were analyzed correctly and new faces have been added to the library. However photos taken since before 2017 have not been autoprocessed after one month of waiting. Therefore I've had to trick Google Photos to think that I've uploaded new pics:

1. Sync your photo folder from Google Drive to your local machine
2. Move the photos from the Google Drive folder to another folder and wait for Drive to sync
3. Move the photos back and wait for Drive to re-uploaded them back to the cloud

A few minutes after re-uploading the photos they should be correctly mapped to your faces library. After a couple of weeks Google Photos will parse any new people and add them to your faces library as well.

Comment: Regarding the update: How?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn Off and On [Face grouping setting in Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/settings). After some time, all faces will be recognized.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such option in Google Photos that would allow enabling/running additional face recognition on chosen images. You should also note that this is just a mare residue of an experimental feature of already discontinued Google +.

Comment: Are you suggesting that facial recognition will be discontinued? It's plainly the _only_ reason I use Google Photo, and even Google's cloud storage—it's the only thing that makes up for the general feature poverty. And the way facial recognition works did seem to change around the time photos in Google Drive stopped being automatically included, so they don't seem to be abandoning it just yet. But if you've seen some notice that they are, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your Google Photos App
- Click Albums
- Click People
- Top right - click 3 dots
- Select Hide & Show People

Voila! You will get a selection of faces from your Google Photos.
Select one at a time and name it. Click Done. This face will be selected into its own album.
Neat.
Repeat for more faces.

Comment: Yes, but the post is about what to do when that doesn't work. You also haven't specified which 'Google Photos App'—do you mean the webapp, or the Android app?